# Issues printing a Dataframe after collecting Data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I hope you can help me with my Issue. I connected python to my database using pyodbc and I think I was able to save the data into a pandas Dataframe, but unfortunatly I cant work with the Dataframe (for example simply print it) aftertwards.
The error Message says "undefined name "DataFrame"".

How do I need to change my Code so I can get the data from MySQL and use the Dataframe afterwards regularly.

Just as a side Information I want to calculate with the dataframe a little using pandas (optional) and then create a plot using Plotnine and add a UI later. just in Case that matters.

```
#This function I call
def SQLtoPandas(Connection,SQLString,DataFrame):
    DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(
            pd.read_sql(SQLString, 
                        con=Connection)
            )


#If i call this function it works just fine
def SQL_ReadFunction(Connection,SQLString):
    cursor=Connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
            SQLString
            )
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)


SQLString = 'select * from employees'



SQL_ReadFunction(Connection,SQLString)


Connection.close

#Doesnt work, moving it inside the connection also doesnt help.
print (DataFrame)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have a few things to take care:**

- Your function can directly have `pd.read_sql` as it will load your table as a dataframe. You do not need an extra `pd.DataFrame`.
- You have to print your dataframe inside the function, or assign the dataframe outside like `df = SQLtoPandas(Connection,SQLString)` and have a `return df` inside your function
- Avoid using the keyword `DataFrame` to name your DataFrame, use df or something else that is not reserved.

---

## Method 1:

Inside your function:

```
def SQLtoPandas(Connection,SQLString):
    df= pd.read_sql(SQLString, con=Connection)
    print(df)
```

Now call your function outside:

```
SQLtoPandas(Connection, SQLString)
```

## Method 2:

Inside your function:

```
def SQLtoPandas(Connection,SQLString):
    df = pd.read_sql(SQLString, con=Connection)
    return df
```

Now outside your function do:

```
df = SQLtoPandas(Connection, SQLString)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need additional function for this. just use

```
df=pd.read_sql('select * from employees',con=con)
print(df)
```

and manipulate df as you wish using pandas.
i would reccomend using jupyter notebook as it displays dataframe nicely.

also note pd.read_sql() already returns pandas DataFrame, no need to reconvert

Comment: Thanks alot this was quick and awsome, now can go on :)
also @Ankur Sinha off course!!